# Use of an ArrayList of HashMaps

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

Could someone tell me what is wrong with the code below? When I run the code below the first line after the try { produces the following error :

"java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0"

```
public static class ASIFFile {
            private ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> data;
            private static int currRec = 0; //assign each record a numeric id based on this figure.

            // Method for reading ADIFfile  
            public ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> ReadASIFfile (File DataFile) {      
                data = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>(500);

                try {
                        HashMap<String, String> temp = new HashMap<String,String>(10);
                        data.set(currRec, temp);                        
                        (data.get(currRec)).put("recID", Integer.toString(currRec));//give the record a numeric ID


...
```

Comment: The second line barks for a semicolon :)

Comment: @Eich ah, that was a mistake copying to the text box. It was actually there in the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Kevin mentioned, you never put anything in your ArrayList.  Your code should look something like this...

```
data = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>(500);

try {
    //give the record a numeric ID
     data.add(currRec, temp);
```

In your previous solution, you're calling data.set(currRec, temp); which assumes there is a HashMap element in position currRec of your ArrayList.  If you haven't put anything in the ArrayList yet, there will be no element currRec.

Comment: thanks for the help, the problem was that I was doing data.set instead of data.add!

Answer (score 6):

You never add anything to your `ArrayList`. You have an `ArrayList` that *can* hold `HashMaps`, but is currently empty.You have to add a new `HashMap` to the index you want to use before you use that index.

Comment: I changed it to `HashMap<String, String> temp = new HashMap<String,String>(10);
     data.set(currRec, temp);
           (data.get(currRec)).put("recID", Integer.toString(currRec));`              but I'm still having the problem. Do you have any other suggestions?